# Ubuntu 14.04.2: sound behaves strangely

Tags: ubuntu, audio

I just installed an Ubuntu-Mate 14.04.2 partition and my sound is behaving strangely.  The first thing is that the audio jack in the back (connected directly to the motherboard) doesn't work. it produces no sound.  There's a workaround for this though, that the headphone jack in front and the orange jack in the back both DO work.

The annoying thing is that the volume buttons on my keyboard don't control the volume.  The little dialog pops up when I press that that shows the volume going up and down, but the actual volume doesn't change at all.  The only way to change the volume is to click the volume indicator on the top panel and drag the slider.

Comment: Have you tried re-installing Alsa and Pulse audio?
First uninstall them using `sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base pulseaudio`.

Next install them back using `sudo apt-get install alsa-base pulseaudio`.

Finally reload Alsa using `sudo alsa force-reload`.

Reboot and see if it solves the problem.

Comment: @Ayan I did try that.  Though I'm not sure if I did them both at the same time.  I'll give it a shot after work.